# Problem when redirecting standard output with dup and dup2 in c

Tags: c, file, descriptor, dup2, dup

I have a problem with dup and dup2.

```
int copy (char * file1, char * file2) {
        int dr = open(file1, O_RDONLY);
        if (dr == -1) {
                return -1;
        }

        int dw = open(file2, O_WRONLY|O_TRUNC|O_CREAT, 0644); 
        if (dw == -1) {
                return -1;
        }

        int save0 = dup(0); 
        int save1 = dup(1); 

        dup2(dr, 0); 
        close(dr); 

        dup2(dw, 1); 
        close(dw); 

        char c;
        while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) {  
                putchar(c); 
        }

        dup2(save0, 0); 
        dup2(save1, 1); 

        printf("Hi");
        return 0;
}
```

I don't understand why the data from my file file1 is displayed on the screen because dr is standard input and dw is standard output...

Thanks for the help.

Comment: You didn't flush stdout before you switched out the underlying file descriptor.  The call to `putchar` put the data in a buffer.  Then you switch the underlying fd to be the original stdout.  Then the buffer is flushed.

Comment: And `char c;` is wrong when used in `while ((c = getchar()) != EOF)`.  `EOF` is an `int` value that can not match any `char` value, which is why `getchar()` returns and `int` and not a `char`.  By cramming the returned value into a `char`, you can not reliably detect `EOF`.  You also need to check the return values from all your `dup()` and `dup2()` calls - if you run up against an open file descriptor, they can and will fail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You (probably) just need to flush the buffers:

```
while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) {  
        putchar(c); 
}
fflush(stdout);   /* Actually write to the file */
dup2(save0, 0); 
dup2(save1, 1);
```

Since you haven't included the full code, it's hard to be certain.  Also, make sure you haven't done any `read`-like functions (eg `fread`, `fgetc`, etc) on stdin before this function is called.